# Post array via jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, post

I have a form which contains some unique input fields and some others with duplicate names, like this:

```
<form method="post">
  Title: <input type="text" name="title" /><br />
  Content: <input type="text" name="content" /><br />
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
</form>
```

So 'title' and 'content' are just string values, but 'name' and 'email' send an array of strings to the destination.  This is what I want.  I will store the title and content values into a table, and save the name/email combinations as rows in a different table.

If I post this form in the standard way (just by specifying an 'action' parameter in the form tag) then the values are sent to an ASP.NET page and can be processed as strings and string arrays and in theory they can be quite easily inserted into a database.

However, the application won't allow the form to be submitted in the traditional way.  Instead I must use jQuery AJAX to post the form.

The question is, how do I replicate the behaviour of a traditional form post, maintaining array values, using jQuery AJAX?

I know it's possible to serialize the form values but then I need to do some server-side logic to deserialize and effectively create the array, which is an extra step.

Does anyone know of a way to just replicate the same behaviour in passing a string array through jQuery AJAX as when doing a standard form post?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [$.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [$.serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to serialize form fields to send them using ajax like following

```
$.post('URL',$('form').serialize(),function(data){
     // success
})
```

Read more on [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: I believe this is only when using PHP, otherwise PHP just uses the last item rather than creating an array of all items with the same name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543500/php-form-input-field-names-containing-square-brackets-like-fieldindex

Answer (score 6):

You can use jQuery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)() function like so:

```
<form method="post" id="testform">
  Title: <input type="text" name="title" /><br />
  Content: <input type="text" name="content" /><br />
  Name: <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br />
  Email: <input type="text" name="email[]" /><br />
  Name: <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br />
  Email: <input type="text" name="email[]" /><br />
  Name: <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br />
  Email: <input type="text" name="email[]" />
</form>
```

...

```
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());
```

Comment: why do you put the **[]** ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales: To tell php it's an array

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({

  url: "form.aspx", 
  data: $("form").serialize(),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'json',
  method: 'POST',
  success: function() {

  }
});
```

Read about [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You have also option [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

And in short use can you [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

you just need this in javascript,you can put your all data in array and in ajax data send array, in server side you can explode

```
   var myarray=array();
   myarray[]='mytestvaliye1';
   myarray[]='mytestvaliye2';
   myarray[]='mytestvaliye3';

   $.ajax( {
   url :  'myrurl',
   data : myarray, 
   success: function (){}
   }

   )
```