# URL Parameters with brackets

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: form input field names containing square brackets like field[index]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543500/php-form-input-field-names-containing-square-brackets-like-fieldindex)

I just saw a URL parameter with brackets in it, does anyone know what could be the reason for using brackets?

`www.website.com?request[product]=Digital+Printing`

Thanks

Comment: insanity? Probably the same thing that makes people delimit params in get urls

Answer (score 4):

you can pass parameters in the format to make arrays

```
<input type="text" name="request[product]" value="..."/>
<input type="text" name="request[item]" value="..."/>
```

> www.website.com?request[product]=Digital+Printing&request[item]=something

so in the back end you can access it like so:

```
echo $_GET['request']['product']; // Digital Printing
echo $_GET['request']['item']; // something
```

Answer (score 4):

Its for passing arrays.

```
//Example: ?request[product]=Digital+Printing&request[key]=abc123
var_dump($_GET['request']);
/**
 * array (size=2)
      'product' => string 'Digital Printing' (length=16)
      'key' => string 'abc123' (length=6)
 */
```

Its used more in POST for sending multiple values with the same key name, like a multi select option or checkboxes.

Answer (score 3):

`$_GET['request']` is an array so it is represented has `request[product]`

if you run

```
  var_dump($_GET);
```

You would get

```
array
  'request' => 
    array
      'product' => string 'Digital Printing' (length=16)
```