# Python/Django: How to deserialize foo[]=1&foo[]=2&

Tags: python, django, get, deserialization

Is there a pre-built deserializer for query strings like:

```
foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=34&....&foo[]=5
```

Currently I am just working the string with `replace` and `split` to get a sequence with all the values, but I am curious if there isn't some utility/helper method in Python or Django to do this.

Obviously Django is able to do very similar things when processing requests, but I **a)** don't know if/how I can use it and **b)** if it is possible to receive a sequence from the `foo[]` notation.

*Note:* I am not able to change the source string, since it originates from a third party package.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your replies. My values come from POST, so I did the following (not sure if there is a more direct way, like the answers used with `request.GET.getlist()`):

```
foo = QueryDict(request.POST.get('my_var_name')).getlist('foo[]')
```

Comment: Pre-build parser? I don't even know what `foo[]=1` means.

Comment: @freakish: Probably jQuery; it's PHP's notation for an array being posted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I've misunderstood. I thought he somehow wants to retrieve `foo` from that string.

Comment: @freakish: see [Form input field names containing square brackets like field\[index\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4543500)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see, thank you. Yet another reason not to use PHP. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just retrieve all values with the [`getlist()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

```
foo_list = request.GET.getlist('foo[]')
```

*Include* the brackets, they are just part of the name.

Comment: +1 for linking to the QueryDict docs. Useful read up and exactly what I was hoping to find. As noted, the part generating the bracketed string lives in a third party tool that I want to leave unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there's absolutely no reason to send data with the `[]` prefix. That's a PHP or Rails idiom, and has no place in Django.

To get a list from a repeated parameter, though, you can just use `getlist`:

```
foos = request.GET.getlist('foo[]')
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I believe you can disable that in jQuery by setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`.

Comment: Ah, I knew I'd missed a switch somewhere. Indeed, `traditional = true` will disable the dismal default setting.

Comment: I'd really like to accept both of your answers. Came in exactly the same time. Super useful information with the ```traditional``` setting in jQuery.