# Sending a form array to Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have an HTML form with multiple inputs named like this:

```html
<input name="hello[]" type="text" />
<input name="hello[]" type="text" />
<input name="hello[]" type="text" />
```

In **PHP** you get this as an array but is it the same way in Python, using Flask?

I have tried this:

```
hello = request.form['hello']

print(hello)
```

But that did not work, I got a `400 Bad Request`:

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

How do I do it in Flask?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You are following a [PHP convention of adding brackets to the field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543500/form-input-field-names-containing-square-brackets-like-fieldindex). It's not a web standard, but because PHP supports it out of the box it is popular; Ruby on Rails also uses it.

If you do use that convention, to get the POST data on the Flask side you need to *include* the square brackets in the field name. You can retrieve *all* values of the list using [`MultiDict.getlist()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist):

```
hello = request.form.getlist('hello[]')
```

You don't have to use the `[]` convention at all, of course. Not appending the `[]` to the `hello` name will work perfectly fine, at which point you'd use `request.form.getlist('hello')` in Flask.

Comment: What if my input is something like this: `hello[][some_sub_field]` in forms that send form array of objects?

Comment: @RocketPingu: You'd have to extract those by full name again. Don't use that format when posting to Flask, basically.

Answer (score 7):

I written a parse function which supports multidimensional dict:`php_post=parse_multi_form(request.form)`

```
def parse_multi_form(form):
    data = {}
    for url_k in form:
        v = form[url_k]
        ks = []
        while url_k:
            if '[' in url_k:
                k, r = url_k.split('[', 1)
                ks.append(k)
                if r[0] == ']':
                    ks.append('')
                url_k = r.replace(']', '', 1)
            else:
                ks.append(url_k)
                break
        sub_data = data
        for i, k in enumerate(ks):
            if k.isdigit():
                k = int(k)
            if i+1 < len(ks):
                if not isinstance(sub_data, dict):
                    break
                if k in sub_data:
                    sub_data = sub_data[k]
                else:
                    sub_data[k] = {}
                    sub_data = sub_data[k]
            else:
                if isinstance(sub_data, dict):
                    sub_data[k] = v

    return data
```

Usage:

```
>>> request.form={"a[0][name]": "ahui", "a[0][sex]": "female", "a[1][name]": "bhui", "a[1][sex]": "male"}
>>> parse_multi_form(request.form)
{'a': {0: {'name': 'ahui', 'sex': 'female'}, 1: {'name': 'bhui', 'sex': 'male'}}}
```

> **Warnning:** It does not support list,e.g. `a[][0]=1&a[][0]=2`, it may make programmer to be confused.
>   Either `a=[[1,2]]` or `a[[1],[2]]` is too hard to choose.

So I suggest use dict to replace list:

```
<input name="hello[0]" type="text" />
<input name="hello[1]" type="text" />
```

If you still want to post complex data, I suggest you use `application/json`

Answer (score 1):

I have a form that has arrays with either one or two levels, so either `a[1]` or `b[1][2]`.

I've written a regex solution to get this into the dict with posted data.

```
import re

re_post = re.compile(r'([a-z_]*)(\[(.*?)\])?(\[(.*?)\])?')

for post_key, post_value in request.form.copy().items():
    matches = list(re_post.findall(post_key)[0][0::2])

    if matches[1]:
        request.form.setdefault(matches[0], {})

        if matches[2]:
            request.form[matches[0]].setdefault(matches[1], {})
            request.form[matches[0]][matches[1]][matches[2]] = post_value
        else:
            request.form[matches[0]][matches[1]] = post_value
    else:
        continue
    
    del request.form[post_key]
```

So it iterates over the form keys/values and matches 3 groups in the key: first the 'base' name, and then the names of two levels. If either first or second level name is present, it will create a dictionary and populate it with the posted value and then proceeds to remove the original key/value.