# Parsing a nested form array in Flask, with support for using getlist() on elements that have several values

Tags: python, flask

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819417/12718345), I have a nested array structure being submitted by a form to Flask.

However, my values **can** sometimes come from a multiselect dropdown (several values) and othertimes not, so I may need to parse them one step further with [getlist](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.MultiDict.getlist.html) but not always.

Here is an example of `request.form`:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('name', 'sadfsdaf'), ('description', ''), ('step_action[0]', 'forward'), ('step_values[0]', 'North America'), ('step_values[0]', 'South America')])
```

Notice how there are two values for `step_values[0]`.

Normally, you would access these elements with:

`request.form.getlist('step_values[0]')`

I found a [helper method](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819417/12718345) to parse the POSTed data into a nested array structure, but it doesn't support calling `getlist` if there are multiple values.

Helper Method:

```
def parse_multi_form(form):
    """Returns a dictionary containing complex (multi-dimensional) form data."""
    """https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819417/12718345"""
    data = {}
    for url_k in form:
        v = form[url_k]
        ks = []
        while url_k:
            if '[' in url_k:
                k, r = url_k.split('[', 1)
                ks.append(k)
                if r[0] == ']':
                    ks.append('')
                url_k = r.replace(']', '', 1)
            else:
                ks.append(url_k)
                break
        sub_data = data
        for i, k in enumerate(ks):
            if k.isdigit():
                k = int(k)
            if i + 1 < len(ks):
                if not isinstance(sub_data, dict):
                    break
                if k in sub_data:
                    sub_data = sub_data[k]
                else:
                    sub_data[k] = {}
                    sub_data = sub_data[k]
            else:
                if isinstance(sub_data, dict):
                    sub_data[k] = v

    return data
```

Output:

```
{
  'name': 'sadfsdaf',
  'description': '',
  'step_action': {
    0: 'forward'
  },
  'step_values': {
    0: 'North America'
  }
}
```

How can I modify the output to support multiple values under a single key, like this?

```
{
  'name': 'sadfsdaf',
  'description': '',
  'step_action': {
    0: 'forward'
  },
  'step_values': {
    0: ['North America', 'South America']
  }
}
```

Note the addition of `South America` under `'step_values'[0]` above.