# Python and Requests module, correct syntax for 'payload' in url-encoded POST method

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests

I'm using the Requests module and Python 3.
when I inspect in Chrome, If the parsed form data is listed as:

```
   list_class_values[notice][zipstate]:
   list_class_values[notice][type][]:
   list_class_values[notice][keywords]:colorado
```

In the above case, I'm searching for 'colorado'.
What is the proper syntax to list them in the 'payload' section, given the below code snippet?
the content-type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

```
payload = {"list_class_values[notice][zipstate]":"None", "list_class_values[notice][type][]":"None", "list_class_values[notice][keywords]":"colorado"}
r = requests.post(url='http://www.example.com', payload=payload, headers=headers)
print(r.content)
```

Do I need a tuple in there somewhere? e.g. "list_class_values(notice,keywords)":"colorado" ?
as the data doesn't change when I change the keyword..

Comment: The other fields are *blank strings*, not the string `"None"`. The field names are otherwise correct.

Comment: The brackets are a Ruby-on-Rails and PHP convention; there is no standard describing these, but square brackets are parsed by such servers to produce a nested array structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the other fields that are the issue here. Their values are *empty strings*, not the string `"None"`:

```
payload = {
    "list_class_values[notice][zipstate]": "",
    "list_class_values[notice][type][]": "",
    "list_class_values[notice][keywords]": "colorado"
}
```

The form field names are otherwise correct; the syntax is a convention used by Ruby on Rails and PHP, but is otherwise not a standard. Servers that support the syntax parse the keys out into array maps (dictionaries in Python terms). See [Form input field names containing square brackets like field[index]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543500/form-input-field-names-containing-square-brackets-like-fieldindex)

Note that you need to pass this to the `data` argument for a POST body (there is no `payload` keyword argument, you should get an exception):

```
r = requests.post(url='http://www.example.com', data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Yes, this worked i.e using "" and also changing the parameter from 'payload' to 'data'. Thank you Martijn.